# Best way to add replay gain to m4a files?

Tags: rhythmbox, quodlibet, replaygain

I use (and love) QuodLibet as a my music player and it has a plugin that calculates replay gain values (album and track) and stores them in the files.

However, [it doesn't work for my m4a files](https://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/issues/detail?id=323)...just my mp3 and flac.

Any suggestions for a tool that will do this on Ubuntu 12.04+

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without any other answers, I am choosing to convert my m4a files to mp3 files and then go from there.

Comment: have you ever heard of [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss)?!? that's a reason why [ReplayGain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReplayGain) was introduced. - i hope you reserved the original files!!!

Answer (score 1):

I realise this question was asked some time ago, but I was also looking for an answer.  gmusicbrowser has an option in its settings to add replaygain tags to your collection, and it seems to work with M4a files too.  I'm using Debian Jessie, but I see no reason why it wouldn't work on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

well, a while ago `aacgain` (with the same command-line interface as `mp3gain`) was in the medibuntu-repositories, now i use this ppa: [ppa:flexiondotorg/audio](https://launchpad.net/~flexiondotorg/+archive/ubuntu/audio)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flexiondotorg/audio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y aacgain
```

---

if you prefer a gui i can recommend [`qtgain`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qtgain/) (the version in the repositories is pretty old - i installed the deb-file from the hompage manually); it works with m4a- (`aacgain`), mp3- (`mp3gain`), flac- (`metaflac`) and ogg-vorbis-files (`vorbisgain`) if the corresponding backends are present:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y qtgain aacgain mp3gain flac vorbisgain
```